# how can remove last dropdown divider class in list items on vuejs

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with dropdown divider, I use bootstrap on vuejs and I have list items I'm gonna add a line between that list, for that reason I used of `dropdown-divider` class, it works, but I want to remove the last line of that, how can I do this?

here it's my codes:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item" v-for="nav in navbar" :key="nav">
     <nuxt-link :to="nav.link" class="nav-link">{{
            nav.item
     }}</nuxt-link>
     <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the index property.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="nav-item" v-for="(nav, index) in navbar" :key="nav">
     <nuxt-link :to="nav.link" class="nav-link">{{
            nav.item
     }}</nuxt-link>
     <div class="dropdown-divider" v-if="index !== (navbar.length - 1)"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```